# Create props object inline

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to create a props object inline? I am looking to do something like:

```
<Component {{id: 1, ...rest}} />
```

However, this is not a valid syntax.

Btw, I know I could just do:

```
const props = {id: 1, ...rest};
<Component {...props} />
```

but I want to know if there is way to do it in one line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create props inline as you require. One way to achieve this is to adjust your code as follows:

```
<Component {{...{ id: 1 }, ...rest}} />
```

This is equivalent to spreading the `{ id: 1 }` object and `rest` object, into a new object which is then in turn passed to the `<Component />`.

In a simple case like yours however, you might consider doing the following instead:

```
<Component id={1} { ...rest } />
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont really get why {{id: 1, ...rest}} is not a valid syntax, though